# does icloud sync cydia apps as well?

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud

Can you add an app downloaded from Cydia to iCloud, so it will sync to all your jailbroken iDevices? I wonder what content iCloud does sync and does not sync, is it folder specific?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: no.

Long answer: it only works with Apple's own apps as well as apps downloaded from the official App Store.

Answer (score 1):

It's not folder specific, but it is app specific. iCloud syncs apps from the app store only. It also syncs documents (like pages and numbers files) and media (like photos).